# when I use asmx service and SSRS report service I am getting "The request failed with http status 401: unauthorised"

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008

I was trying to call report related service (asmx) from my asp.net web application by running locally. 
Then an exception happened saying. `The request failed with http status401:unauthorised`.

In my analysis I understood the issue caused due to below code

```
SSRSWebService.ReportingService2005 rs = new SSRSWebService.ReportingService2005();
rs.Credentials = new MyReportServerCredentials().NetworkCredentials;
```

and

```
Uri reportUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerManagement.ReportingService2005"]);
this.rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new MyReportServerCredentials();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my detailed analysis I understood that the issue was because of the credential set up in **serviceObject.credential** OR **ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials** was wrong. This can be rectified in two different way either by setting credential to default with below code

```
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;//"rs" is report object
```

Or locate below code and set up proper authenticated user credential in the code

```
 public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
{
    get
    {
        // Use the default Windows user.  Credentials will be
        // provided by the NetworkCredentials property.
        return null;
    }
}

public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
{
    get
    {
        // Read the user information from the Web.config file.  
        // By reading the information on demand instead of 
        // storing it, the credentials will not be stored in 
        // session, reducing the vulnerable surface area to the
        // Web.config file, which can be secured with an ACL.

        // User name
        string userName =
            <<AccurateUserName;>>


        // Password
        string password =
            <<AccuratePassword;>>

        // Domain
        string domain = <<AccurateDomainName;>>


        return new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
    }
}
```

In order to check whether which user has the access, we need to type service url ending with asmx (*http:/MyServiceHostedServer/MyService.asmx*) in a web browser. It will prompt a user name and password . Give our username as :**Domain\Username** and password.If we are able to see wsdl xml file then that user has the access.